# HTML 2 column layout - Applying background color the top level container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 2 column layout with my html and its just not happening. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Welcome</title>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    font: normal 12px/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #132959;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}


.outer{
    width:970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
}

.toc{
    width:250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    color:yellow;
}

.content{
    padding: 0;
    width:720px;
    float:right;
    color:white;
}
.container{
    width:970px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

.logo a{
    color : #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: bold 40px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.logo small {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 80px;
    font: normal 12px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #EDF3F6;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.logoimage {
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="logo"> 
    <a href="http://www.csmart.co.in">Csmart 
    <small>Let's make life easy!</small> </a> 
</div>
<div style="clear:both;padding:15px"/>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="toc"> 
  TOC
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Welcome
  </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- outer-->
</div>
```

My div outer is coloured black. But it does not show up on the screen. If I give a height to .outer.. then it shows up. But it doesn't have to be this way.. I can't predict the height of the page. Why doesnt the background colour of the div outer not show up on the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your inner elements are floated, and therefore have no height. You will need to unfloat one of the inner elements, provide a height for the container element, or add a clearing div after the `outer` element.

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:hidden to your .outer like in this fiddle I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/nTxWC/

And I would reccomend you to do all your css code in the css part of the page, otherwise it gets pretty messy !

Answer (score 0):

Because your inner content are floated. Put `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of your `.outer` div and you will see it.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/hBP63/